# Print python xml response into HTML page

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

My .py app return xml response from API, I want to write value of messageKey 'notFound' into the .html page.

Ex of response:

```
<response>
<returncode>FAILED</returncode>
<messageKey>notFound</messageKey>
<message>We could not find a meeting with that meeting ID</message>
</response>
```

EX of .html:

```
#....
<div class="row">
   <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
#....
```

Any kind of help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this by:

.py:

```
@flask.route('/admin')
def index():
    return render_template("admin.html", variable=soup)
```

.html:

```
<div class="row">
  <p>{{variable}}</p>
</div>
```